# C# TablelayoutPanel Drag item from one cell to another cell?

Tags: c#

How do I use mouse to drag item from one cell to another cell??

I used this way:
[Move Item from one cell to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677919/move-item-from-one-cell-to-another)

But only a question is the form will twinkling when mouse down and move.

Please tell me how to solve it.

Thanks a lot.

This is my first post.
If have some bad words in post, tell me please.

Comment: `But only a question is the form will twinkling when mouse down and move.` what do you mean by this? Maybe I'm able to help

Comment: Crystal ball says that you skipped the DoubleBuffered hack in that code.  Now it twinkles.

Comment: Actually,It's TableLayoutPanel twinkles not the form.
And I mean this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nB-b4N3WyI&feature=youtu.be